# How to fetch a directory name in php

Tags: php, input

i have a question that how to get name of a directory that is dynamically created?
explanation-:
i create a file upload type and one submit button whenever i clicked submit button then directory is created if not exist with logged in username. but file is not stored there because i can't get a name of directory to store that file.
i want how to get that name which function is used in php to get name of directory that is created dynamically.

```
//$image = $_GET['upload'];
$upload = $_POST["submit"];
session_start();
$_SESSION['x'] = "username";
$path = "upload/";
$image_name = $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
$temp = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
if(isset($upload)){
mkdir($path.$_SESSION['x']);
$new = ""//what function I used here to fetch the name of directory in last step
move_uploaded_file($temp,$new.$image_name);
}
```

Comment: More people with PHP knowledge would see your question if you tagged it as PHP. :)

Answer (score 1):

The directory name is `$path.$_SESSION['x']`.

Comment: yes, if directory is not available then it will created with user name